# Yahoo Finance cant be read

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am a user of the Yahoo Finance API. I have recently be recieving errors saying that the program is unable to read the website. Here is the error message:

Pls note I am using Pandas Datareader for this.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sande/Dropbox/My PC (DESKTOP-BOCOF1O)/Desktop/Vihaan/ThirdPartySoftware/Python/DadWork/Downloaders/YahooDownloader.py", line 38, in <module>
    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(str(file_name), start, end)
  File "C:\Users\sande\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-BOCOF1O)\Desktop\Vihaan\ThirdPartySoftware\Python\DadWork\Downloaders\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 86, in get_data_yahoo
    return YahooDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()
  File "C:\Users\sande\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-BOCOF1O)\Desktop\Vihaan\ThirdPartySoftware\Python\DadWork\Downloaders\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 253, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "C:\Users\sande\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-BOCOF1O)\Desktop\Vihaan\ThirdPartySoftware\Python\DadWork\Downloaders\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
    resp = self._get_response(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\sande\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-BOCOF1O)\Desktop\Vihaan\ThirdPartySoftware\Python\DadWork\Downloaders\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError(msg)
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILD/history?period1=1152743400&period2=1626215399&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
Response Text:
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n  <html lang="en-us"><head>\n  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n      <meta charset="utf-8">\n      <title>Yahoo</title>\n      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">\n      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">\n      <style>\n  html {\n      height: 100%;\n  }\n  body {\n      background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;\n      background-size: cover;\n      height: 100%;\n      text-align: center;\n      font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n  table {\n      height: 100%;\n      width: 100%;\n      table-layout: fixed;\n      border-collapse: collapse;\n      border-spacing: 0;\n      border: none;\n  }\n  h1 {\n      font-size: 42px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      color: #400090;\n  }\n  p {\n      color: #1A1A1A;\n  }\n  #message-1 {\n      font-weight: bold;\n      margin: 0;\n  }\n  #message-2 {\n      display: inline-block;\n      *display: inline;\n      zoom: 1;\n      max-width: 17em;\n      _width: 17em;\n  }\n      </style>\n  <script>\n    document.write(\'<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t=\'+new Date().getTime()+\'&src=aws&err_url=\'+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+\'&err=%<pssc>&test=\'+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\')+\'" width="0px" height="0px"/>\');var beacon = new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+new Date().getTime()+"&src=aws&err_url="+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+"&err=%<pssc>&test="+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\');\n  </script>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n  <!-- status code : 404 -->\n  <!-- Not Found on Server -->\n  <table>\n  <tbody><tr>\n      <td>\n      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_frontpage_en-US_s_f_p_205x58_frontpage.png" alt="Yahoo Logo">\n      <h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>\n      <p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>\n      <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>\n      </td>\n  </tr>\n  </tbody></table>\n  </body></html>'
```

and this is the main code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import os
import datetime
import openpyxl

# Paths for loading file to read
path_file = os.getcwd() + "\\Book1.xlsx"
path = os.getcwd() + "\\historicalData"

# Load File
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_file)

sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
max_row = sheet_obj.max_row

# Get 15 years ago date
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
dt = dt.replace(year=dt.year-15)
dty = dt.year
dtm = dt.month
dtd = dt.day

for q in range(1):
    #try:
    for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
        #try:
        cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1)
        file_name = str(cell_obj.value).upper()
        print(file_name)

        # Download Path for data
        download_source = (r"" + path + "\\" + str(file_name) + ".csv")

        start = datetime.datetime(dty, dtm, dtd)
        end = datetime.datetime.today()

        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(str(file_name), start, end)

        df.to_csv(download_source)
        print(df)
"""
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(file_name) + " Not Found!")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
"""
```

(Pls ignore the quotes)

Pls can anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you change your code? Revert those changes then! Did Yahoo change their API? Check their changelogs or similar publications.

Answer (score 2):

Did you even LOOK at the data you got back?

```html
<h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>
<p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>
<p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your library
 `pip install pandas_datareader --upgrade`